# Creating ASYNC task in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, callback, closures

I want to show users current location in map and I know it's not instantaneous task. I want to call my showCurrentLocation() function in the ASYNC task. I was trying to learn call back closures but i could not understand how can I create ASYNC task for this. I know this is not a best question template for stackoverflow but I don't know how can I ask differently. 
Thank you for any help.
Have a nice coding.

Comment: have a look at NSOperation http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/

Comment: Thank you. I will look the NSOperation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the past I've made a class called [AsyncTask](http://pastebin.com/0HSd3jAE) for usage purposes like the one you described here.

Lately I've updated it for **swift 3**

It has 2 generic types:

`BGParam` - the type of the parameter sent to the task upon execution.

`BGResult` - the type of the result of the background computation.

If one of them(or both) isn't needed you can set it to Optional or just ignore.

In code example I refer the functions `showCurrentLocation()` & `getCurrentLocation()` that you mentioned in OP & comments. 
`BGParam` is set to `Int` & `BGResults` is set to `CLLocationCoordinate2D`

```
AsyncTask(backgroundTask: {(param:Int)->CLLocationCoordinate2D in
        print(param);//prints the Int value passed from .execute(1)
        return self.getCurrentLocation();//the function you mentioned in comment
        }, afterTask: {(coords)in
            //use latitude & longitude at UI-Main thread
            print("latitude: \(coords.latitude)");
            print("latitude: \(coords.longitude)");
            self.showCurrentLocation(coords);//function you mentioned in OP
    }).execute(1);//pass Int value 1 to backgroundTask
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a technology called [GCD (Grand Central Dispatch)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/) which you can use to perform such tasks.

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
    // do some task
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // update some UI
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I know the GCD. I wonder, Can I create custom async task with closure ? Think about this situation. 

Lets assume we have a getCurrentLocation() function and it returns us userCurrentLocation.latitude and longitude. I can't get values instantaneously so I have to use callback mechanism. It should tell me we found locations and there are the results so I can use them in main thread. If you put the getCurrentLocation function in the background thread. Does it solve my problem ? Will it work like a callback mechanism ? Thank you !

Comment: using the global queue is not the best idea ... you newer know who use it. creating own concurrent queue is a little bit better solution here.