# Creating an asyncTask in swift

Tags: swift2

How can I create an `asyncTask` in Swift?  I want to call my `loadPage()` function in the background (which will load the page from server), and I want to handle the response in `postExecute(after background task)`

Comment: you can use ` to put around keywords to format them as text.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer.. i want to display the response in tableview @AlBlue

Comment: There are examples in the Swift Essentials repository that correspond to the book, including one which allows you to populate a table view. See https://github.com/alblue/com.packtpub.swift.essentials/blob/master/RepositoryBrowser/RepositoryBrowser/MasterViewController.swift for an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating ASYNC task in Swift 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177362/creating-async-task-in-swift-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Grand Central Dispatch to run threads.

```
class ThreadsFromSwiftEssentialsBook {
    class func runOnBackgroundThread(fn:()->()) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),fn)
    }
    class func runOnUIThread(fn:()->()) {
        if NSThread.isMainThread() {
            fn()
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), fn)
        }
    }
}
```

(Implementation is MIT licensed here: https://github.com/alblue/com.packtpub.swift.essentials/blob/master/RepositoryBrowser/RepositoryBrowser/Threads.swift)

Comment: Thank you,  I will checkout @AlBlue